# How can I set the working directory of a PS Script as the directory where the script exists?

Tags: .net, powershell

How can set the working directory of a Powershell script as the same directory of the script exists so that regardless of the directory you call it from, it will always look up for the files in the root directory of the script?

For example if you call foo.ps1 as below:

```
c:> d:\MyScript\foo.ps1
```

foo.ps1 will set the working directory as d:\MyScript\ so that when it -for example- look up for a configuration file, it will not wsearch it in C:\ but in d:\MyScript\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path to the script's folder is retrieved using the following code:

```
Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

You could use `Set-Location (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)` at the start of the script or you can use `Push-Location (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)` at the start of the script and `Pop-Location` at the end.

Comment: Or you could use `$PSScriptRoot`

Comment: @Graimer If you are in powershell v3.0 ;)

Comment: That's why I didn't submit it as an answer =)